# Third party pack cannot be found likely because the corresponding app is restricted, sdk: 29 ,power saving mode: false

Tags: java, android, whatsapp-stickers

I have to used same method as you say it working when i add sticker from assets it was working but when i have to create my custome stickerpack and add to it whatsapp then getting same issue "**Third party pack cannot be found likely because the corresponding app is restricted, sdk: 29 ,power saving mode: false**"

Comment: same issue, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I also have same issue. Have you found any solution for this? If yes then please post your answer.